# Download list of contact information and check if Google Account

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-contacts, google-apps-script

In order to retrieve a list of all of my contacts into a Google spreadsheet, I exported them as a Google CSV and then imported them into a new spreadsheet.

**Determine if the contact is a Google account**

Is there a function in the Google spreadsheet API that can determine if the contact is a Google account or not?

getIM() is the only one I saw that might be able to do this.

Comment: You can export your contacts to CSV. Have you tried that? Spreadsheets can then import it. You'd just need to clean it up.

Comment: That works great for getting a list of my contacts.  Part 1 solved!  From here, any ideas on how to determine is the contact is a Google account?  Not sure if there is some function I can call.

Comment: That, I can't help with. (Which is why I just left a comment.)

Comment: While questions about using Google Sheets and Google Apps Script are on-topic, questions about the Google Sheets API are off-topic on this site. It's not clear what you mean by `getIM()`. You might add a minimum complete verifiable example, be detailed about what you found https://developers.google.com/apps-script and why it doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do this using the methods of ContactsApp in Google Apps Script. But you can use [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/search#examples) to search, e.g., by email address; this can be done in any language, including JavaScript (the documentation page has sample code and a form you can use to try out this search, so I'm not giving details here).

This will only find people with a public Google+ profile, but this is probably inevitable: after all, just having someone's email address shouldn't entitle you to find out whether they have a Google account that they wish to keep private.